# Ubuntu two commands in one line doesn't behave as expected

Tags: bash

I'm logged in as `root` and i do:

```
su killyz && whoami
```

the user will switch but the `whoami` won't print until i `Ctrl+D`, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`su` opens a new shell and won't exit until that shell is closed, via Ctrl-D or some other method.

Comment: so how can i switch user and run commands for it?

Comment: Tell `su` to run your commands.

Comment: can you provide an example please? how do i do that?

Comment: @Killyz have a look at `man su` and its `-c` option: `su killyz -c 'whoami'`.

Comment: it's working.. why can't i run su killyz -c ll? i get a bash: ll: command not found.